# JsonParser returning null instead of values

Tags: json, scala, streaming, jackson

I have a simple Jackson parser, that is supposed to return me values but instead am getting only `null` values. Any ideas will be appreciated?

Sample Json data:

```
{"a":"ab","b":"cd","c":"cd","d":"de","e":"ef","f":"fg"}
```

Code:

```
var jfactory = new JsonFactory()
var jParser : JsonParser  = jfactory.createJsonParser(new File(outputDir + "/" + "myDic.json"))

while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
  var k = jParser.getCurrentName();
  jParser.nextToken();
  var v = jParser.getText();
  println(k +"---" + v)
  phoneDict.put(k,v);
  i = i + 1;
  println(phoneDict.size)
  var t = readLine("Dict Done ?")
}
```

Output:

```
null---null
1
Dict Done ?
null---null
1
Dict Done ?
null---null
1
Dict Done ?
null---null
1
Dict Done ?
```

Comment: that really depends on the content of your json ...

Comment: you are supposed to call `jsonParser.nextToken();` between your 2 `getText`

Comment: the name you will get using `getCurrentName`, too

Comment: I tried having them in the middle as well even then I get null. Sorry, I don't think I have a field name for my objects. They are just of the form, `{ "key1":"value1","key2":"value2",.....,"keyn":"valuen"}`

Comment: `key1` is the "name" field  for the `value1` value.

Comment: `      println(jsonParser.getCurrentName());
       jsonParser.nextToken();
       println(jsonParser.getText());
 ` this is inside my while and still returns `null`

Comment: can you post the complete output for the example input you posted? (also, why are you calling the first `nextToken`?)

Comment: Your JSON is a simple key-value mapping. Why you do not want to deserialize it to `Map`? Java solution: `Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);`

Comment: I never tried using the Java solution.Just learned about JavaConversions as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Java code looks like this and works perfectly fine:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(json);

//Skip START_OBJECT
jsonParser.nextToken();

while (JsonToken.END_OBJECT != jsonParser.nextToken()) {
    System.out.println(jsonParser.getCurrentName());
    jsonParser.nextToken();
    System.out.println(jsonParser.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but if you don't mind can you remove this output part of the solution. This is part of my research data.the reason why I posted it as pastebin file. I know this is against Stack Overflow policies. I will make sure this isn't repeated. I have updated my answer with similar sample data.

Comment: I didn't know. Sorry for that. Done.